# How to escape html for Laravel

Tags: html, laravel

I have a question on it, so this is my output
[image]

and this is my index.blade.php code

```
  <tr>
                    <td>{{$row['policy_category_id']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['policy_title']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['version_no']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['policy_details']}}
                    <td>{{$row['expiry_date']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['file_path']}}</td>

                    <td><a href="{{action('policyController@edit', $row['id'])}}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('policyController@destroy',$row['id'])}}">
                            {{  csrf_field()    }}
                            {{  method_field('DELETE')}}

                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"  />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </form>
```

My question is how to remove those label away but just showing human readable data ?
Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use the `strip_tags` function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
  <tr>
                <td>{{$row['policy_category_id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$row['policy_title']}}</td>
                <td>{{$row['version_no']}}</td>
                <td>{{strip_tags($row['policy_details'])}}
                <td>{{$row['expiry_date']}}</td>
                <td>{{$row['file_path']}}</td>

                <td><a href="{{action('policyController@edit', $row['id'])}}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('policyController@destroy',$row['id'])}}">
                        {{  csrf_field()    }}
                        {{  method_field('DELETE')}}

                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"  />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: No problem, happy coding :)

Comment: It can be very challenging but also very rewarding. Maybe take a break and come back to it. There are always people to help :)